# Updated but packages from NETStandard.Library.2.0.2 could not be found

Tags: package, .net-standard-2.0

I have the latest **VS 2017 Version 15.6.6** and I've updated to **NETStandard.Library.2.0.2**, twice and all is fine until after closing/reopening VS to keep finding out they can't be found:

[image]

but, checking with the **Source Control Explorer**, all the files are there. Is there a way to fix this without uninstalling/reinstalling again to find out it will do this again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is an issue with that version of the package: 
https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/708

Best is to revert to 2.0.1 and wait for an update.
Edit: has been fixed in 2.0.3

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I reverted back to 2.0.1. :)